# How to make camera smoothly follow behind player in Unity 3D?

Tags: unity, 3d, camera

Following the advice posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43709392/camera-always-behind-player-in-unity3d), I made a camera that follows a player behind with:

```
    public Camera roomCam;
    public GameObject playerGO;
    private float camMotionSpeed = 5f;
    private float camRotationSpeed = 50f;

    void Start() {
        camOffset = new Vector3(0, 3, -8);  //x=sideways, y=up/down, z = forward/back
        roomCam.transform.position = playerGO.transform.position + (roomCam.transform.forward * camOffset.z) + (playerGO.transform.up * camOffset.y);
        roomCam.transform.LookAt(playerGO.transform.position);
    }

    private void UpdateCameraPosition() {
        
        //Move
        Vector3 newCamPosition = playerGO.transform.position + (playerGO.transform.forward * camOffset.z) + (playerGO.transform.up * camOffset.y);
        newCamPosition = Vector3.Slerp(roomCam.transform.position, newCamPosition, Time.smoothDeltaTime * camMotionSpeed); //spherical lerp smoothing
        roomCam.transform.position = newCamPosition;

        //Rotate
        Quaternion newCamRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerGO.transform.position - roomCam.transform.position);
        newCamRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(roomCam.transform.rotation, newCamRotation, camRotationSpeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime); //spherical lerp smoothing
        roomCam.transform.rotation = newCamRotation;

    }

    private void LateUpdate() {
        UpdateCameraPosition();
    }
```

This works correctly in general, but the smoothing function which is just meant to make the camera slowly "catch up" in position and rotation to the user as they move around is quite jerky.

Smoothing specifically is done by the lines:

```
        newCamPosition = Vector3.Slerp(roomCam.transform.position, newCamPosition, Time.smoothDeltaTime * camMotionSpeed); //spherical lerp smoothing
        newCamRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(roomCam.transform.rotation, newCamRotation, camRotationSpeed * Time.smoothDeltaTime); //spherical lerp smoothing
```

Is there some better way of smoothing this that can be applied that will not create so much jerking or wobbly jello motion?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered the built-in SmoothDamp functions?

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of that. Something new I learned but it was not the issue. FYI, I did find the issue here: https://forum.unity.com/threads/camera-jitter-problem.115224/ If you're following a physics based object you need to use `FixedUpdate()` not `LateUpdate()`

Comment: If you've solved your problem, be sure to post your solution as an answer below. You can also enable Rigidbody interpolation to smooth the physics object's movement between FixedUpdates

Answer (score 1):

Solution was described here: forum.unity.com/threads/camera-jitter-problem.115224

If you're following a physics based object you need to run `UpdateCameraPosition()` on `FixedUpdate()` not `LateUpdate()`.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted if it worked for you.